# NumberFormatExceptions

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am trying with a Utility function to get int and check if bad input results in
NumberFormat Exceptions,is there a way to work with Non-decimal Int for below function

```
//--- Utility function to get int using a dialog.

public static int getInt(String mess) {
    int val;
    while (true) { // loop until we get a valid int
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, mess);
        try {
            val = Integer.parseInt(s);
            break;  // exit loop with valid int
        } catch (NumberFormatException nx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid integer");
        }
    }
    return val;
}

//end getInt
```

Comment: Please translate `"is there a way to work with Non-decimal Int for below function"` into understandable English for us. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Non Decimal : Convert integers with some base (radix)

Comment: check the [Integer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), as there's an overload of `parseInt(...)` that may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you... maybe you can do this:

```
public static int getInt(String mess) {
    int val;
    while (true) { // loop until we get a valid int
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, mess);
        try {
            if(mess.match("^\d+$")){   // Check if it's only numbers (no comma, no dot, only numeric characters)
               val = Integer.parseInt(s); // Check if it's in the range for Integer numbers.
               break;  // exit loop with valid int
            } else  {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid integer");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nx) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid integer");
        }
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: You might want to apply the same formatting changes of the question on your answer :P

Comment: @Tom Oh, I was so young... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try what u want , one for decimal checker and one for non-decimal int

// for deciaml

```
 public static Boolean numberValidate(String text) {
    String expression = "^[+-]?(?:\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\d*\\.?\\d+)[\\r\\n]*$";
    CharSequence inputStr = text;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.find()) {
       MatchResult mResult = matcher.toMatchResult();
       String result = mResult.group();
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

// non-decimal int

```
public static Boolean numberValidate(String text) {
    String expression = "[a-zA-Z]";
    CharSequence inputStr = text;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.find()) {
      MatchResult mResult = matcher.toMatchResult();
      String result = mResult.group();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```